# Check if date is later than current date

Tags: php, date

How can I check if the date is later than the current date?

```
if(date("d") < "18" && date("m") < "01") { 
    echo 'To late!';
}
```

Doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you want to check if the current date is after something, why are you using less-than?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this notation:

```
if( '20140505' > date("Ymd") ) {
    // today's date is before 20140505 (May 5, 2014)
}
```

Comment: Which requires you to manually construct the date string. I don't think that's a very good idea. Use `strtotime()` - or *even* better, use `DateTime` class.

Answer (score 5):

```
$time1  = strtotime(date("d/m/Y", "18/01/2014"));
  if(time() > $time1)
   {
     echo "too late!";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use strtotime.

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$date_to_compare = date("Y-m-d",time()+86400); //1 day later
if (strtotime($date_to_compare) > strtotime($current_date)) {
   echo "too late";
}
```